# What does memcached "get" return in telnet?

Tags: memcached

When I query a key in memcached using telnet, I see something like this:

```
> get mykeyname
VALUE mykeyname 3 240396
{the key value}
END
```

What is the first line? I can see the keyword VALUE and the name of the key but don't understand what the integers mean, and I can't find this documented anywhere. My guess is that the second integer is the length of the data in bytes, but what is the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the [Memcached protocol](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt#L231), the first integer are the flags and the second integer is the size of the value in bytes.